# How to get API documentation to be shown inside Eclipse Help window?

Tags: java, eclipse, reference, documentation, javadoc

I've downloaded jdk-8u45-docs-all.zip from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk8-doc-downloads-2133158.html), wrote it's link to my jdk's javadoc location in Eclipse. Everything works just well, when I hover over something the tooltip appears, when I press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> offline API documentation opens in browser.

The only thing that doesn't work - When I write some search query in search field of Help window, it always gives me (0 hits) for "Local Help" and several hits under "Web Search". Isn't it supposed to show links to API documentation articles from my offline source?

If I press Contents from Help window, It shows me list of some books which I assume to be sources where it looks for help articles.

There's no "book" with name JDK-8 API documentation. I have just:

- "Workbench User Guide"
- "Java development user guide"
- "Platform Plug-in Developer Guide"
- "Plug-in Development Environment Guide"

Should I add documentation to this list manually? If yes, then how? Or am I getting all this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse 'Help Contents' only shows help for Eclipse components and does not include the JDK help.

Comment: So there's no way for getting what I want?

Comment: Well you could probably write an Eclipse plugin using the Help APIs to do it, but I don't think there is anything simpler than that.